# Oracle Apex - Saving Previously Selected Entries In a Shuttle Item

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently working on a project that uses a cascading list of values as a "filter" for an otherwise very long list.  The "filter" is a select list that then cascades to a checkbox group. The user selects items from the checkbox group and then passes them to another page where the data is used.

It works just how I want it to, but the design has a problem.  Whenever you change the select list value (thus changing the values in the checkbox group) the previously selected values are de-selected.  This makes it impossible to select items from different "lists."

As an odd solution to this problem I backed up the selected values in a table before switching but I was hoping for a better solution with the shuttle page item.

Is it possible for the shuttle page item to save items (or at least appear to) on the right side, then change the contents of the list on the left side and the previously selected items stay?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I wouldn't use a shuttle item or select list for this design pattern. One option is to mimic the shuttle behaviour with 2 reports: one to select the values and one to show the selected values.

- Create your filter select list (let's call that P1_FILTER).
- Create your filtered report (report1) - use where clause
   `WHERE <your_column> = :P1_FILTER` and make sure `P1_FILTER` is in items to submit.
- Create a dynamic action (DA1) on `P1_FILTER` to refresh the filtered report on change
- Add a column to the filtered report with a dynamic action (DA2) to insert the selected row in a collection.
- Create a 2nd report (report2) on `APEX_COLLECTION` to display the selected values
- Add an action to DA2 to refresh report2 whenever a value is selected
- Add a column to report2 with a dynamic action (DA2) to remove the selected row from the collection.